# When is log of sum approximately sum of logs

Tags: calculus, approximation

I've stumbled upon the following approximation which I am a bit baffled by and I hope you could help me get some intuition about when it is reasonable and when it is not.

Let $c_i,a_i,b_i$ for $i=1,\dots,N$ be given and all positive.

It then reads
$$
P(x) =C +  \log (\; \sum_{i=1}^N c_i \exp(- ( a_i+ b_i x) \;) =C -\sum_{i=1}^N c_i  ( a_i+ b_i x ) + \text{correction}
$$
and further goes, since $P$ is then an approximately affine function it is well approximated by a first order Taylor expansion around $x^*$ (satisfying $P(x^*)=0$ known to exist).

Is it possible to say something about when this works well and not? Specifically the final Taylor approximation more than the intermediate step.

Comment: Do we have the condition $\sum c_i = 1$?

Comment: @DanielFischer I would be very interested in if it works in that case!

Comment: The approximation works decently if $\sum c_i = 1$ and all $\lvert a_i + b_ix\rvert$ are small. Then the Taylor expansion of $\log (1-y)$ applied to $\sum c_i\exp(-(a_i + b_ix)) = 1 - \sum c_i(a_i + b_ix) + O\bigl(\sum (a_i + b_ix)^2\bigr)$ produces the given expression. It's generally not a good approximation if $\sum c_i \neq 1$, or any of the $a_i$ or the $b_ix$ is large.